# Keycloak user registration in UI gives me a Invalid username or password

Tags: keycloak

First I have activated the the user registration on the keycloak admin panel

[image]

I try to create a new account with an unique email and username

[image]

This shows up after I click register:
[image: After I try to create a new account]

In console it is this printed:

```
2023-01-06 00:39:50 2023-01-05 23:39:50,440 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-34) type=REGISTER_ERROR, realmId=keycloak-react-auth, clientId=account-console, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/keycloak-react-auth/account/#/,, code_id=c8dccb6d-1ca4-4f25-b160-9b72d48bffd1, authSessionParentId=c8dccb6d-1ca4-4f25-b160-9b72d48bffd1, authSessionTabId=gY0TRMYd8aw
```

Comment: Which kc version are you using?

Comment: @dreamcrash Server Version 18.0.2

Comment: Strange why you don't have the fields for the password?

Comment: I do not know :(, have you any idea?

Comment: Can you share a screenshoot? of the content in Authentication > Flows > and in the dropdown menu select Registration instead of browser and take the screenshoot